# React Native - Check the render method of `TabBarIcon`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I got this issue when render `createBottomTabNavigator` in my app.

```
Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `TabBarIcon`.
```

My code

```
import React from "react";
import { createStackNavigator, createBottomTabNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import { FontAwesome } from "react-native-vector-icons";

import SignUp from "./screens/SignUp";
import SignIn from "./screens/SignIn";
import Home from "./screens/Home";
import Profile from "./screens/Profile";

export const SignedOutNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  SignUp: {
    screen: SignUp,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Sign Up"
    }
  },
  SignIn: {
    screen: SignIn,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Sign In"
    }
  }
});

export const SignedInNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: "Home",
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
        <FontAwesome name="home" size={30} color={tintColor} />
      )
    }
  },
  Profile: {
    screen: Profile,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: "Profile",
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
        <FontAwesome name="user" size={30} color={tintColor} />
      )
    }
  }
});

export const SignedOut = createAppContainer(SignedOutNavigator);
export const SignedIn = createAppContainer(SignedInNavigator);
```

Reference: https://github.com/datomnurdin/auth-reactnative

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with the `FontAwesome` icon that is being imported. The library doesn't seem to have named export for `FontAwesome` as a default.

Instead import it as

```
import FontAwesome from "react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome";
```

Answer (score -1):

If you did not see your icon, on android, run command

```
cd android && ./gradlew
```